# Using DescriptionAttribute in Domain Entities

Tags: c#, .net, oop, attributes, domain-driven-design

I am currently developing a system that needs to expose some of its metadata/documentation at runtime. I know there are methods of using XML Comments and bringing that data back into the app via homegrown Reflection extension methods.

I feel it might be easier to use the description attribute from the System.ComponentModel namespace (but located in System assembly). This way I and other developers would be able use regular reflection to get the Description of fields. I much rather use this than using a custom attribute. What are the downsides to this approach?

Example:

```
public Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Description("The common friendly name used for the customer.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Description("The name used for this customer in the existing Oracle ERP system.")]
    public string ErpName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is more of a statement than a question. What are you asking?

Comment: try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing the exact same thing (with ERP software no less!) and have encountered no drawbacks. One thing you may consider a drawback in your situation depending on your architecture is that many documentation tools are directly or indirectly based on XML comments. They will likely not be able to pick up description attributes. But in our architecture, the Description attribute code is not actually the master/source of the documentation. We have a database of MetaData that defines and describes every property. We can generate XML comments *and* Description attributes from that same source. Actually in our case, we do not generate the XML comments at all, but instead directly generate the XML file that would normally be generated by the XML comments directly. That's the file used by the documentation tools we use. You could probably write a simple utility to extract the description attributes into a similar XML file if you want to use documentation tools that rely on the xml file output by xml comments, if it can't accept the Describiton attribute directly.

Comment: Good thoughts +1. One thing that still "smells" to me about XML Comments and Attributes is in both situations you are required to update your C# source files to correct documentation. You seem to handle this well with your external source (database). Any negatives you have encountered with your approach?

Comment: No negatives. On the contrary, using a "meta-database" has provided us many unexpected benefits (the more code you can include in and generate from Meta-data, the more control you have to mass-change and query it). When we want to mass-search or change certain patterns or types of objects, it's often a simple matter of an SQL query. You just have to be thoughtful when designing your meta-data schema and the code generators around it. Partial classes are very useful in code generation. If I'm really pressed to think of a drawback, source control is less than ideal for database table data.

Comment: I have used partial classes with code generation before. Used it to generate C# and Java matching DTOs. It is awesome. Thanks. Will discuss with my team and we will make the attribute vs database decision next week. Good insight.